# Como puedo hacer una validación, poner un mensaje y utilizar un radio button

Tags: asp.net, razor

Estoy haciendo un programa en asp razor, en el cual es de un cinepolis y me debo ingresar el nombres, cuantos compradores, cuantos boletos, obtener el total y lo que debe de hacer es hacer descuentos si es mayor a 5 aplica un descuento, si es mayor de 3 tambien y menor o igual que 5 otro descuento y si es menor a dos ya no aplica ningun descuento.Pero por ejemplo si es mayor a 7 tiene que aparecer un mensaje de no se puede comprar mas boletos y de los radio button como los puedo colocar ya que va ver dos radio button si selecciono uno me tiene que hacer un descuento del 10 porciento y el otro no debe hacer descuento.

```
public void GuardarArchivo(Datos d)
            {
                var nombre = d.Nombre;
                var compra = d.Compradores;
                var boletas = d.Boletas;
                var total = d.Total;
                d.Precio = 12;

if (d.Boletas > 7)
                    {
}                    
if (d.Boletas > 5)
                {
                    d.Descuento += 0.15;
                }
                if (d.Boletas >= 3 && d.Boletas <= 5)
                {
                    d.Descuento += 0.10;
                }
                if (d.Boletas <= 2)
                {
                    d.Descuento += 0.0;
                }



                double descuentoAplicado = (d.Precio * d.Boletas) * d.Descuento;
                d.Total = (d.Precio * d.Boletas) - descuentoAplicado;



                var datos = nombre + "," + compra + "," +  boletas + "," +Convert.ToString(total)+","+  Environment.NewLine;

                var archivo = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/datos2.txt");
                File.AppendAllText(archivo, datos);

            }
```

Y este es mi index

```
  @model ManejoArchivos.Models.Datos

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Cinepolis";
    }

    <h2>Cinepolis</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Cinepolis", "Cinepolis2", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(Mode => Model.Nombre, new { htmlAttribute = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Compradores, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(Mode => Model.Compradores, new { htmlAttribute = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Boletas, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(Mode => Model.Boletas, new { htmlAttribute = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Total, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Total, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Cinepolis" class="btn btn-info" />
                </div>
            </div>
  <div class="form-group">
            <input type="radio" name="colors" id="si">
            <div class="col-md-10">

            </div>
  <div class="form-group">
            <input type="radio" name="colors" id="no">
            <div class="col-md-10">

            </div>
                </div>
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifique tu metodo un poco, porque veo que pasabas tus propiedades a variables declaradas en el momento que no tenia sentido cuando ya tenias los valores guardados en tu modelo Datos, luego te cambie la asignacion de `+=` por `=` porque supongo que no aplicabas descuentos acumulativos por cada compra que se hiciera.
Con un solo radioButton lo solucionas, ya que si queres aplicar descuento lo usas y si no queres aplicar descuento simplemente no lo seleccionas.
Se me hace confuso que quieras una logica para aplicar descuento y luego uses un boton para aplicarla. Creo que no te haria falta.

```
    public void GuardarArchivo(Datos d)
    {
        d.Precio = 12;
        if (d.Boletas > 7)
           {
             Response.Write("<script>alert('No se puede comprar mas de 7 entradas')</script>");
             return;
           }
        if (radio1.Checked)
        {
          if (d.Boletas > 5)
          {
            d.Descuento = 0.15;
          }
          if (d.Boletas >= 3 && d.Boletas <= 5)
          {
            d.Descuento = 0.10;
          }

          if (d.Boletas <= 2)
          {
            d.Descuento = 0.0;
          }
        }
        double descuentoAplicado = (d.Precio * d.Boletas) * d.Descuento;
        d.Total = (d.Precio * d.Boletas) - descuentoAplicado;

        var datos = d.Nombre + ", " + d.Compradores + ", " + d.Boletas + ", " + Convert.ToString(d.Total) + "," + Environment.NewLine;

        var archivo = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/datos2.txt");
        File.AppendAllText(archivo, datos);

    }
```

Comment: una pregunta por ejemplo tengo que poner si es mayor a 7 me tiene que aparecer un mensaje diciendo no se puede comprar de mas boletos como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: colocalo en tu pregunta inicial y te modifico la respuesta.

Comment: listo ya lo puse

Comment: quisiste hacerlo sobre la respuesta. debes hacer la modificacion sobre tu pregunta

Comment: si perdon ya lo puse